# Confusion with computing kernel of an isogeny between two elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Consider the two elliptic curves $$E_3: y^2+y=x^3+x^2+x \enspace [Cremona:19A3]$$ and $$E_1: y^2+y=x^3+x^2−9x−15 \enspace [Cremona:19A1]$$ Let $\varphi$ be the $3$-isogeny from $E_3$ to $E_1$. I want to prove that kernel of $\varphi$ contains a point over the rationals. I have computed the isogeny in Magma.

Input:

E:=EllipticCurve("19a3");
E2:=IsogenousCurves(E)[2];
A,B:=IsIsogenous(E,E2);
A;
B;
Kernel (B)

Output:

true
Elliptic curve isogeny from: CrvEll: E to CrvEll: E2
taking (x : y : 1) to ((x^3 + 2*x + 1) / x^2 : (x^3*y - 2*x*y - x - 2*y - 1) /
    x^3 : 1)
Subgroup scheme of E defined by x

Now $E_3$ contains the rational $3$-torsion points $(0,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$. Since the isogeny map contains 'x' in the denominator, my confusion is where will the above 3 points be mapped ? Also, if someone can help me to find out a rational point in Ker $\varphi$, I will be very grateful.

Comment: I don't think there are many that know what elliptic curves "Cremona this and that" are...

Comment: The "Cremona this and that" refers to Cremona's database and notation to classify classes of elliptic curves, as in http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/ftp/data/

Comment: @Andrew not sure if I am misunderstanding your notation or if somehow the characteristic of the base field is 2; but naively the point (0,1) is not on E3 !  The rational 3-torsion points are the other two you mention together with the point at infinity.

Comment: @GaryMak Write down the equation of $E_3$ in projective coordinates. Then (0,1,0) is a point on $E_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the isogeny is defined in projective coordinates, you can write it as well in this form:
$$[x:y:1] \mapsto [x(x^3+2x+1):x^3y-2xy-x-2y-1:x^3].$$
Now it is clear that $[0:0:1]$, $[0:1:1]$, and $[0:-1:1]$, map to $[0:1:0]$, the point at infinity in $E_1$. Indeed, they map to $[0:-1:0]=[0:-3:0]=[0:1:0]$, respectively, which are all the same point in projective coordinates, equal to the point at infinity. In other words, all three points are in the kernel of the map.